# How do I keep track of automatically instanced unassigned objects in basic Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop

I am trying to build a mastermind game, and I am hoping to have my code instance its own objects containing information about the place and color of the step in the passcode. This is so I can vary the length of the passcode without hard coding it. Is there a way to keep track of these objects, seeing as I am not personally assigning a variable? Can my program assign the instances their own variable names, and if so how would I do that?

```
#Builder for password objects
class ColorPicks
  attr_reader :color, :place
  def initialize(color, place)
    @color = color
    @place = place
  end
end

# Determines how long the password should be
module StartUp
  def self.how_many
    @how_many
  end
  def HowManyColors 
    p "How long should the computer's code be?"
    @how_many = gets.chomp.to_i
  end 
end

#Instances the password objects from ColorPicks
class Printer
  include StartUp
  @@i = StartUp.how_many
  @@place = 1
  COLORS = {1 => 'red', 2 => 'blue', 3 => 'green'}

  def self.code_maker
    for a in 1..@@i do 

      number_of_colors = COLORS.length
      random_number = rand(number_of_colors)
      ColorPicks.new(COLORS[random_number], @@place)
      @@place += 1
    end
  end
end
```

PS. Sorry, I am new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References to objects are stored in variables, like the *instance variable* `@color` in your `ColorPicks` class. Only the instance itself can access the instance variable directly. Other objects can only access it indirectly via method calls, e.g. `attr_reader :color` creates a `color` method that returns the object, `@color` is referring to.

If you want to store a variable number of objects, you typically use a *collection* like [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/Array.html), [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/Hash.html) or [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/stdlibs/set/Set.html). Instead of assigning every single object to a separate variable, you add the objects to the collection and just assign the collection to a variable, e.g.

```
class CodeGenerator
  COLORS = %w[red green blue]

  attr_reader :code

  def initialize(size)
    @code = Array.new(size) { COLORS.sample }
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
generator = CodeGenerator.new(5)
generator.code
#=> ["blue", "green", "red", "blue", "red"]
```

The object returned by `generator.code` is the array we assigned to `@code` in `initialize`. To access individual objects in the collection, you can use [`Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#5B-5D-method): (note that arrays are zero based in Ruby)

```
generator.code[0] #=> "blue"
generator.code[1] #=> "green"
```

In the above example, I'm using plain strings to keep the code simple. The concept however applies to all objects, i.e. you could just as well add instances of `ColorPicks` instead of strings. You also don't have to use the [`Array.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#new-method) constructor to build an array. It's perfectly fine to start with an empty array and to add your items in a loop one after another, e.g.:

```
def initialize(size)
  @code = []
  (1..size).each do |i|
    @code << ColorPicks.new(COLORS.sample, i)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write some variant the following, where all instances created are saved to an array held by a class instance variable.

```
class ColorPicks
  @instances = []
  class << self
    attr_reader :instances
  end

  attr_reader :color, :place
  def initialize(color, place)
    self.class.instances << self
    @color = color
    @place = place
  end
end
```

Note that `@instances` is a class instance variable and its getter is created in `ColorPick`'s singleton class.

---

Create an instance.

```
stefan = ColorPicks.new("blue", "Bremen")
  #=> <ColorPicks:0x00007fba7bb29958 @color="blue", @place="Bremen">
```

Then,

```
stefan.color
  #=> "blue"
stefan.place
  #=> "Bremen"
```

We can now see the instances of `ColorPicks` that have been created:

```
ColorPicks.instances
  #=> [#<ColorPicks:0x00007fba7bb29958 @color="blue", @place="Bremen">]
```

---

Now create a second instance.

```
cary = ColorPicks.new("blue", "Victoria")
  #=> #<ColorPicks:0x00007fba7babc7e0 @color="blue", @place="Victoria">
```

Then,

```
cary.color
  #=> "violet"
cary.place
  #=> "Victoria"
```

Now,

```
ColorPicks.instances
  #=> [#<ColorPicks:0x00007fba7bb29958 @color="blue", @place="Bremen">,
  #    #<ColorPicks:0x00007fba7babc7e0 @color="Violet", @place="Victoria">]
```

Comment: Lovely example data :-)